# cakephp 3 Image upload by Utils Behavior

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using this plugin http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/behaviors/uploadable/#configurations to upload image in cakephp 3. Here image name is saving database well, but problem is image not uploading in path. Here is the code in model that I have tried

```
 $this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
            'banner' => [
                'field' => 'id',
                'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}{WEBROOT}{DS}uploads{DS}',
                'fileName' => '{field}.{extension}'
            ],
 ]);
```

I have created a folder in my webroot folder calls uploads.But no any file is saving in uploads folder, but name is saving in database table.

Comment: Have you checked your error log to see if any errors are being recorded and also checked the chmod of the directory you have created.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with it for a long time. Finally tried to resolve it by myself. This plugin has a bug in it. Look for aftersave function in the Uploadable behavior.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    $fields = $this->getFieldList();
    foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
        if ($this->_ifUploaded($entity, $field)) {
            if ($this->_uploadFile($entity, $field)) {
                if (!key_exists($field, $this->_savedFields)) {
                    $this->_savedFields[$field] = true;
                    $event->subject()->save($this->_setUploadColumns($entity, $field));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_savedFields = null;
}
```

After the FIX:

```
public function afterSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    $fields = $this->getFieldList();
    foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
        //LINES ADDED - Start
        if(isset($_FILES[$field])){
            $entity->{$field} = $_FILES[$field];
        }
        //LINES ADDED - end
        if ($this->_ifUploaded($entity, $field)) {
            if ($this->_uploadFile($entity, $field)) {
                if (!key_exists($field, $this->_savedFields)) {
                    $this->_savedFields[$field] = true;
                    $event->subject()->save($this->_setUploadColumns($entity, $field));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->_savedFields = null;
}
```

This should fix your problem. :)

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien Have you tried debugging anything on this line? What does `$_FILES` gives at the line where I added the fix? What does `$entity` give there?